# Add a sequence of n numbers, getting n from another list, in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I have the following two lists:

```
numlist = [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2]
lenwords = [2,3,5]
```

I want to see the number at each index in len words as such:

```
for number in range(len(lenwords)):
    print(lenwords[number])
```

And then take that number of items in numlist suggested by each index in lenwords (2,3,5) and add them together, like so:

```
add 1+1 then 1+1+4 then 1+1+4+1+2
```

I'm thinking that I could use itertools, but not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I make an iterable out of numlist, then iterate over lenwords, using itertools.islice to pull out the count you want from the numlist generator.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice

```
import itertools

def sumlengths(numlist, lenwords):
    numbers = iter(numlist)
    for length in lenwords:
        yield sum(itertools.islice(numbers, length))

numlist = [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2]
lenwords = [2,3,5]
print (*sumlengths(numlist, lenwords))
```

> 2 6 9

I did not validate the length of the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

with out using ittertools:

```
numlist = [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2]
lenwords = [2, 3, 5]
counter = 0
for number in lenwords:
    q = numlist[counter:counter+number]
    print(sum(q))
    counter += number
```

## output

```
2
6
9
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
numlist = [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2]
lenwords = [2,3,5]
gen = iter(numlist)
result = []

for n in lenwords:
    total = 0
    for _ in range(n):
        total += next(gen)
    result.append(total)
```

The resulting list `total` is `[2, 6, 9]`, as desired.